# Aurelia Validation and event publish not updating values in View

Tags: aurelia

I was using **Event aggregate publish** method to update view from another view. when I created publish and subscribe data was able to get in view model , but that is not updating in view with assigned variables. If I use JavaScript to fill value it's working but not able to trigger validate controller.

**Expected result is:**

1. From the subscribe method I have to fill the view values.
2. After that it should trigger validate on value changes.

In below gist run I have two view and view-model. One is registration-form and second one is data-form. In data-form I have table with data, on click of each row I am publishing one event with selected row data, and this published event I was subscribing in side of registration-form view-modal. For more details look into below gist run.

**Gist run**: **https://gist.run/?id=8416e8ca1b9b5ff318b79ec94fd3220c**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two possible solutions:** *(to your "undefined" alert)*

1. Change `alert(this.email);` to `alert(myself.email);`
2. Use the thick arrow syntax for the subscribe function.  Change:
   `this.ea.subscribe('MyrowData', function(obj){`
   to
   `this.ea.subscribe('MyrowData', obj => {`
   This syntax allows the new function to preserve the context/scope of the parent, which means that `this.email` will still be accessible.

**Another suggestion:**

You could simplify your **data-form.js** function as follows:

Change:
`this.eventAggregator.publish('MyrowData', this.items[this.items.indexOf(item)]);`
to:
`this.eventAggregator.publish('MyrowData', item);`

This will work because you've already provided `item` in your function call `click.delegate="PopulateData(item, $event)"`.

In fact, you could even delete `$event` and `event` from the two `PopulateData` definitions (in **data-form.js** and **data-form.html**).

When I implement these suggestions, your data is also validated correctly.

Comment: Thanks I am using var myself = this; then it's rendering the values into  view.

Comment: Great.  FYI, it's probably a better practice to use the thick arrow syntax and NOT use `myself`.  If you do #2 above, you can replace all of the `myself` references to `this` and completely delete the `myself` variable.  It will make for cleaner code.

Comment: Awesome, Today I understand coding skills by reaching you.